# New Relic Browser cannot find name newrelic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, newrelic, react-error-boundary

I am using **New Relic Browser** to report error in my React application. Recently I introduced *ErrorBoundary* component from *react-error-boundary* package that seems to block sending any error to New Relic and I have to do it with custom *onError* method, like this:

```
  ...
  const onError = (error: Error) => {
    newrelic.noticeError(error);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={FallbackComponent} onError={onError}>
          <Layout>
            ...
          </Layout>
        </ErrorBoundary>
    </Router>
  );
   ....
```

But I'm not able to make this newrelic invoke work, now I've got an issue saying: **Cannot find name 'newrelic'.** How to make Typescript recognize that I have newrelic in the context when there is no npm package that New Relic shares with developers?

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error. I found solution from other gist https://gist.github.com/piotrkubisa/4a1cc7355afcec46651a896d59ec8d50. Or you can directly go to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/new-relic-browser . copy the value from `index.d.ts` to your desire location, also don't forget setup `tsconfig.json` with key `files`.